# SQL Query from c# class

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to modify my code by placing the SQL connections and queries into a C# class because currently all my `.aspx.cs` has connection strings with different types of queries with parameters

Like this:

```
string CS2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(CS2))
{
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT nombre FROM [Portal_B2e].[dbo].[usuarios] WHERE numero_personal = " + lblCedula.Text + "", con2);
    con2.Open();
    object labels = cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
    lblNombre.Text = labels.ToString();
}
```

As you notice I complete the query with `lblCedula.Text` so when I try to do this from a C# class it says `lblCedula` does not exist in this content.

How could I make a reference to the label I have in another page from the class?

This is my code in the C# class

```
public static List<Perfil> DeletePerfil()
{
    List<Perfil> listDelete = new List<Perfil>();

    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCSATE"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT nombre FROM [Portal_B2e].[dbo].[usuarios] WHERE numero_personal = " + lblCedula.Text + "", con);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
             Perfil perfil1 = new Perfil();
             perfil1.perfil = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["perfil"]);
             perfil1.descripcion = rdr["descripcion"].ToString();

             listDelete.Add(perfil1);
        }
    }

    return listDelete;
}
```

Comment: `DeletePerfil(string labelText)` ?

Comment: Don't make a reference to the label, instead pass it's values as an argument to your function.  Also you really need to use sql parameters to avoid sql injection.

Comment: And use parameter binding instead of simply concatenating the string. This is exactly the case where SQL injection is possible.

Comment: The label is what the user entered in a page before this page, so I need the reference to the label because the results dependes on what the user entered in  a checkbox earlier

Comment: @HansAjani - that fine to accept what the user inputs, but make sure you sanitise the input first and use parameter binding. If you don't you will be open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Im reading about SQL injections now, and there is a lot i still need to learn. thanks for the comments all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have said, pass in lblCedula.Text as a string parameter to your DeletePerfil method:

```
public static List<Perfil> DeletePerfil(string numeroPersonal)
...
```

Then your call looks like this:

```
...
var deletedProfiles = YourClass.DeletePerfil(lblCedula.Text);
...
```

And like sstan's comment mentioned, make sure you use SQLParameters instead of using string concatenation to avoid a SQL Injection security hole.

Comment: Ok, i understand the theory now,

But i still dont understand how or what i need to place in the query instead of the label

Is it something like this?  

 "public static List<Perfil> DeletePerfil(string numeroPersonal)"...... then "SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT nombre FROM [Portal_B2e].[dbo].[usuarios] WHERE numero_personal = " + numeroPersonal + "", con);"  ??

Comment: As a direct replacement of your existing code, yes. What we're also suggesting (strongly) is that instead of using string concatenation, you generate your query string using SQL Parameters: http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! It worked... Let me try with the parameters now

Answer (score 1):

You can hand over the string by a method parameter.

Also please mention the use of the SqlParameter. It will prevent your Query from [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

```
public static List<Perfil> DeletePerfil(string numeroPersonal)
{

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT nombre FROM [Portal_B2e].[dbo].[usuarios] WHERE numero_personal = @PersNo", con);
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@PersNo";
            param.Value = numeroPersonal;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

         ...
        }
}
```